# Arabic and English Sentence direction

Tags: php, string, replace, unicode, arabic

My problem is I need to replace the @ mark in my arabic sentence with an english user name , but this make the sentence strangely mixed and confusing

If the sentence before replace is :
قام @ بإضافة رأي عنك

It appears like :
‏قام Abdo بإضافة رأي عنك‎

It expected to be :
بإضافة رأي عنك‎  Abdo ‏قام

This is my code :

```
        $notification_ar = str_replace("@", $user_name . " ", $notification_ar);
```

any solutions please !?

Comment: Interesting, I was viewing your strings [on `babelstone`](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html?string=%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%85%20@%20%D8%A8%D8%A5%D8%B6%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%A9%20%D8%B1%D8%A3%D9%8A%20%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%83) and tried to fiddle together some regex to exchange parts before `@` and after: Replace [`(?|()(.*)@$|^(.*)@(.*))`](https://regex101.com/r/2DsOHj/2) with `$2 Abdo $1` to achieve your desired result. You'd need to trim spaces after it. See [PHP demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/KtPqu#v8.2.10). Not sure how well this works for your, it's just an experiment playing around with.

Comment: You're welcome, I found it still had a little flaw. If `@` appears at the start of the string. To fix it, try this variant: [`(?|^@(.*)|()(.*)@$|^(.*)@(.*))`](https://regex101.com/r/2DsOHj/3) (same replacement). If you tested it and it works, I can add an answer if you like.

Comment: The issue is not related to the replacement but how the string is rendered.

Comment: Also see [this non regex demo](https://3v4l.org/M9ZHt#v8.2.10) which illustrates what above pattern does. Final regex version: [`(?|^@(.*)|()(.*)@$|(.*)@(.*))`](https://regex101.com/r/2DsOHj/5) Hope that helped. :)

Comment: I don't know anything about RTL languages or non-Latin scripts, but I can speculate you need to insert [right-to-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) and [left-to-right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) marks.

Comment: Every Unicode character has a directionality, and an associated _bidirectional type_ (weak/strong/neutral). For example, in your sample text the Arabic characters are right-to-left and are _strong_ types, the `@` symbol is a _neutral_ type with no explicit directionality, and the Latin characters are left-to-right, and are _strong_ types. How a mix of such text is rendered is specified in a document titled [UNICODE BIDIRECTIONAL ALGORITHM](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/). As Alvaro mentioned, the default rendering can be overridden/corrected using control characters.  ..

Comment: ... Though not a duplicate of your question, see [Why Unicode u+202e and u+202c cause output text to have a different result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72051853/2985643). It is a Java question and does not mention Arabic text, but relates to the same underlying issue of rendering text when portions of it have differing strengths and directionality. I find the topic very complex, but the short answer is that you will need to insert some control characters in your text so that it renders correctly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053204/2985643) for more details on that.

Comment: @Olivier There is no issue with the rendering per se - the text is (probably) being rendered  correctly. The issue is that when the text contains a mix of left-to-right and right-to-left characters, the Unicode rules determining the rendering of that text are very complex, and may not result in the desired/expected output. If so, the user must embed control characters (e.g. U+202E (Right-to-Left Override)) within the text to get the desired result.

Comment: I found the Unicode document [Writing Direction and Bidirectional Text FAQ](https://unicode.org/faq/bidi.html) helpful. Also see [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm basics](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics) for an overview of the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm.

Comment: Your string is 'U+0642 (ق) U+0627 (ا) U+0645 (م) U+0020 ( ) U+0041 (A) U+0062 (b) U+0064 (d) U+006F (o) U+0020 ( ) U+0628 (ب) U+0625 (إ) U+0636 (ض) U+0627 (ا) U+0641 (ف) U+0629 (ة) U+0020 ( ) U+0631 (ر) U+0623 (أ) U+064A (ي) U+0020 ( ) U+0639 (ع) U+0646 (ن) U+0643 (ك)' so string appears fine, the issue is that you are rendering the string in an LTR rather than an RTL environment. For bidi text it is important to get the initial embedding (default text direction) right. But since you are also inserting Latin text you also need to be careful there.